# Github Action: run one step before matrix combinations

Tags: github, build, github-actions

I'm creating a Github Action Workflow.
There is a phing build file that creates multiple zips depending on product variations. This is done with a matrix.

Before the product is build there is a JS File that needs to be build. That's done with a rollup build file.

Everything works fine, but the JS build only needs to be done once and not with every matrix combination.

I don't know how that should be done. Maybe with a single separate workflow running at start, but how would the finished JS file be pushed into the next workflow? Or maybe one workflow is fine?

```
name: Build

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      VERSION: 1.0.1
    strategy:
      matrix:
        edition: ["product1", "product2", "product3"]
        limits: [100, 200, 300]
        exclude:
          - edition: product1
            limits: 100
          - edition: product2
            limits: 100
          - edition: product1
            limits: 200
          - edition: product2
            limits: 200
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build JS
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
      - name: Cache Node.js modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.OS }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.OS }}-node-
            ${{ runner.OS }}-
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build # builds main.js

      - name: Phing Build
        uses: phingofficial/phing-github-action@main
        with:
          repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          buildfile: build/phing/build.xml
          targets: main
          user-properties: editions=${{ matrix.edition }} limits=${{ matrix.limits }}
          version: 3.0.0-alpha4

      - name: Archive code
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: file-${{ matrix.edition }}${{ matrix.limits }}-v${{ env.VERSION }}
          path: build/${{ matrix.edition }}/zip/
          retention-days: 1
```

Comment: One option to do this: separate job that uploads an artifact, which is downloaded in the matrix job

Comment: @riQQ it might be an improvement but it will still download the same artifact multiple times - that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: the fact that this is not supported is ridiculous. Coming from other CI/CD tools, github actions, for our use-cases, is the worst choice. It lacks so many things that come implied for other tools.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute creating the JS File in a separate job (let's name it `prepare`) and then reference that job in the job with the matrix definition (`build`) using the `needs` keyword. Sharing files across jobs is something that GitHub is very specific about: not each job needs all files from a previous job, so you will need to upload and download that file yourself.

Example setup:

```yaml
jobs:
  prepare:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
      # upload the file here for later use
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact


  build:
    needs: prepare
    strategy:
      matrix:
        edition: ["product1", "product2", "product3"]
    steps:
      # download the file here so you can use it
      - uses: actions/download-artifact
```

See the docs on the `needs` keyword [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds).